# Automatic field values changed according to master table field modified In Axapta

Tags: axapta

I have two table WI_MachineDrawing and BOM. There is two common filed call RevNo and WI_MachineDrawngNumber. Now I want to do something when i alter Wi_MachineDrwawng filed RevNo then BOM RevNo should be modified according to WI_MachineDrawing RevNo field.

Answer (score 1):

Override the modifiedField method on the table WI_MachineDrawing to update the field in BOM when RevNo changes:

```
public void modifiedField(fieldId _fieldId)
{
    BOM BOM;
    ;
    super(_fieldId);
    switch(_fieldId)
    {
        case fieldnum(WI_MachineDrawing, RevNo):
            update_recordset BOM 
                setting RevNo = this.RevNo
                where BOM.WI_MachineDrawingNumber = this.WI_MachineDrawingNumber;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But Now I have another problem when i Changed values from WI_MachinDrawing table The Value not refresh Automatically. i Have to Manually close and open the Form then it take effects. I have Modified method on RevNo field in BOM and refresh dataset but it wan't work. Please give me your Valuable Suggestion. Thank you