# Can a field be calculated based off another field?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

In Dynamics Ax 2009, we want a field that will be calculated based off another field in the same table.

Although it might be nice to use a display method or something, we have to actually store the value (management is scared of dynamic calculations because the previous product used them and was slow (like anything in AX is fast!)).

To put the icing on the cake, they want it to work two-way:

If we have FieldA, calculate and store FieldB.
If we have FieldB, calculate and store FieldA.
If we have both or none, do nothing.

Is there anything built into Dynamics AX that can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, override table's method `insert()`, e.g.:

```
public void insert()
{
    ;

    this.FieldB = this.FieldA * 2;

    super();
}
```

Then override `update()`, e.g.:

```
public void update()
{
    if (this.FieldA == this.orig().FieldA && this.FieldB != this.orig().FieldB)
    {
        this.FieldA = this.FieldB / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        this.FieldB = this.FieldA * 2;
    }

    super();
}
```

These are only examples, use your own judgement how the methods should be overridden. Lastly, override `modifiedField()`, which will be used only when the fields are modified manually in forms:

```
public void modifiedField(fieldId _fieldId)
{
    ;

    super(_fieldId);

    switch (_fieldId)
    {
        case fieldnum(MyTable, FieldA) :
            this.FieldB = this.FieldA * 2;
            break;

        case fieldnum(MyTable, FieldB) :
            this.FieldA = this.FieldB / 2;
            break;
    }

    if (this.isFormDataSource())
        this.dataSource().refresh();
}
```

P.S. Keep in mind that `insert()` and `update()` are not called when you are using `doinsert()`, `doupdate()`, or `skipDataMethods()`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to override the modifiedField? Don't the insert, update methods cover user editing through forms?

Also, thanks for the answer.

Comment: If `modifiedField()` is overridden and a user changes FieldA, FieldB will be changed immediately. Otherwise it will be changed only when the record is saved. It is not critical for data consistency and is added for user convenience only.

Comment: @10p: when the `insert()` and `update()` would be called? Could you explain a little further?

Comment: Ah I see - the user will see the other field change more immediately. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

See another related answer here:
[Automatic field values changed according to master table field modified In Axapta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674719/automatic-field-values-changed-according-to-master-table-field-modified-in-axapta)